# Set the row height of tableview dynamically in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am having an app in which I have a tableview on my first view.

I am creating the custom tableviewcell on my tableview's second row.

```
cell1 = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell1 == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell1 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
```

My Custom view's size varies accordingly as there are dynamic contents loading in it.

So how to calculate the size of custom tableviewcell and pass it to the main tableview?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath;
{

    return Your_Height_Here;
}
```

Comment: I have already used this delegate method but I don't know how to pass the height dynamically.

Comment: @Manthan : ok, what are the content inside row you have?

Comment: can you please come in chat room? I'll show you my code there.